# Piglatin to find if a column contains the contents of another column

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a seemingly very simple problem but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I have data that looks like this :

```
A (B, C, A)
B (X, Y, Z)
C (F, C, D)
```

I am using Pig latin to check if the text in the first column is present in the second column.

This is my code for now:

```
Labels = LOAD 'example.txt' USING PigStorage('\t');

Projected = FOREACH Labels GENERATE $0 AS id, $1 AS group;

X = FILTER Projected BY (group matches '.*(chararray)id.*');

STORE X INTO '/test' USING PigStorage(',');
```

The output I am expecting is:

```
A (B, C, A)
C (F, C, D)
```

I also tried concatenating the ".*" to the id but it was of no avail.

I've been stuck with this for quite sometime and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems, one you can't name your variable group because that's a reserved word, two you're matching the string "(chararray)id", not the id.

Also IMO I think it's cleaner never to assign variables by index, and just to define them in your load statement, you can remove the Projected alias if you do this.

```
Labels = LOAD 'example.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS
   (id:chararray, stringvalue:chararray);
X = FILTER Labels BY (stringvalue matches CONCAT(CONCAT('.*',id),'.*'));
STORE X INTO '/test' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Tested this, it worked.

Comment: Remember CONCAT can take more than 2 parameters.